# Whitelisting URLs required for pbiviz

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, pbiviz

I'm trying to install pbiviz on a box with a whitelist in place.

I'm following the instructions here and have nodejs installed:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/environment-setup

I've whitelisted:
https://registry.npmjs.org/powerbi-visuals-tools

I run "npm i -g powerbi-visuals-tools@latest" and it looks like it installs fine

[image]

But when I run "pbiviz" command after, I receive the error:

"pbiviz - The term pbiviz is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet, function..."

Am I required to whitelist an additional URL?

Thanks

Comment: it was required to write .\pbiviz.ps1 in the relevant folder